# Test if char after minus is a number

Tags: java

I have this String `9 $ -2 -`. I want to test if the next of `-` is a number.

```
if (ch == '-') {
    if (ch != input.length() - 1) {
        char next = input.charAt(j + 1);
        if ((next >= '0' && next <= '9') || next == '.')
            temp = temp + ch;
    }
}
```

I can't find how to do it while if `-` may be in the last of String

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 8
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
    at ParsePost.doParse(ParsePost.java:24)
    at InfixApp.main(InfixApp.java:20)
```

Comment: where does the variable `j` come from ?

Comment: char next = input.charAt(j + 1); This  condition is wrong

Comment: Very long app! The problem isn't in `j`

Comment: I haven't seen the rest of your code, but you might want to investigate regular expressions.

Comment: where is your `while` loop?

Comment: well if `-` will be at last of the string then its next value will surely be null...you can compare them...i guess

Comment: try this: `if (ch == '-' && j < input.length() - 1)`

Comment: exception says **idex out of range**. the thing that might be causing this is the var `j`. it must be causing the overflow. and what is `ch != input.length() - 1`?your comparing a character to a index?whats that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's `ch` - the character, or the index (position) of the character in the input string? The first line assumes the former, the second - the latter. Maybe you want `if (j != input.length() - 1)` instead.